# Chrome extension not changing DOM correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, google-chrome-extension

I just starting chrome extension programming. I have some experience in js and html programming. As my first extension I wanted to get rid of the ad bar on facebook. It is an div with the class "ego-column". Here is my code:

```
{
 "name": "DOM",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Change DOM",
    "browser_action": {
    "name": "Manipulate DOM",
    "icons": ["icon.png"],
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
    "content_scripts": [ {
        "js": [ "jquery.min.js", "background.js" ],
        "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
    }]
}

background.js:
$("body").css("background-color","green");
$(".ego-column").empty();
```

The background color correctly changes to green (very beautiful :) But nothing changes with the "ego-column". Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mispelled the class name. It should be `ego_column`. So the fixed code will be:

`$(".ego_column").empty();`